# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^4} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^4} - \frac{1}{8} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^4} $

Tags: summation

Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^4} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k^4} - \frac{1}{8} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^4}  $

I don't really know what to do, I tried expanding it and then seeing if I could group terms together however that didn't really help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Write $\frac{1}{8}$ as $\frac{2}{2^4}$, and look at it for a bit.

Comment: Oh ok ill try that